# is there a way to handle key events in a widget/service?

Tags: android, android-widget, media, android-service

I would like to handle the `volume up` and `volume down` keyEvents in my App Widget.
It really should happen in the `app widget` or a Service, not in an Activity (the homescreen should be displayed).

But as far as i know there don't seems to be a possibility to react with the user from an app widget or service, so i can't get the keyEvents.

So my Question is if I'm wrong and there is a possibility to get the keyEvents or maybe one to make the acitivity invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a trick. It's not really the best, but in my case I can use it.

With assigning the themes

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

or

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

in the Android Manifest, it's possible to have an Activity that looks like an Dialog or which is transparent. So the home screen is visible and in the Activity I can get the keyEvents.

Although it isn't possible that the user can interact with the home screen during the activity is running, but in my case this isn't needed necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

If by "Widget" you mean "app widget", then, no, you cannot respond to key events from an app widget.

Comment: @tschob: Yeah, I really wish Google would have come up with another name for "app widget" that didn't make us constantly wonder if "widget" means something like `TextView` or if "widget" really means "app widget"...